# Adding a row into a sheet using NetOffice

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, office-automation, netoffice

I have a

```
Excel.Workbook book = application.Workbooks.Open(txtPathExcel.Text);
Excel.Worksheet mainSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book.Sheets[1];
```

How can i add a new row in mainSheet? I can't find any NetOffice functions for it.

Comment: Netoffice is *Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop Assemblies*, So you could use the same code /syntax that you would use when working with excel Interop directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows are already exist in the sheet, you just need to select the required.

The [Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197831(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Application class returns a Range object that represents all the rows on the active worksheet. For example:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3)
```

The range object refers to the third row on the sheet.

Also you may find the [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840310(v=office.15).aspx) method helpful. It inserts a cell or a range of cells into the worksheet or macro sheet and shifts other cells away to make space.